# How to link to other pages in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

How do i make a link to antoher page with asp.net MVC? I want to link to an page named overview through my homepage(index page). I have made an view function with my HomeController. When i click "Go To View" my overview page show up. But my hyperlink still dont work on my index page. Anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

**Here are my controller**

```
 public IActionResult Overview()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**Here are my hyperlink**

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("Overview", "Home")" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
```

**here are my overview page i want to display**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Overview";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Overview";
    Layout = "~/Views/Home/Overview";
}

<h1>Overview</h1>

@RenderBody()
```

**Code for my Layout Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>BugTracker</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--FontAwsome Link-->
    <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    @RenderBody()

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading"><h2>Hello<i class="fas fa-bug"></h2></i></div>
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Overview", "Home")" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Projects</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Tickets</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></button>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Projects</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tickets</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Overview</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1 class="mt-4">Welcome User <i class="fas fa-bug"></i></h1>
                <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
                <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: press F12 after you click the link and click on "Console" see if you are getting an error

Comment: Hi @Daniel Eriksson, After changing the code as sassygirl said, have you solved the problem? If not try to use F12 developer tools to check whether there have any error. Besides, you could also set a break point in the OverView action method, then debug your code check whether this action method is executed or not.

Comment: Hi! @ZhiLv I did as sassygirl mentioned. When i check my URL iam at HOME/Overview. So i guess there is nothing wrong with the hyperlink anymore. But the view i get is only a ”crasched” version of my index site. When i press f12 an get in developer tools I have 7 errors message about i cant load bootstrap json etc. Im using a template for my index site. Something i have missed ?

Comment: When using F12 developer tools, [check the request status in the Network panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Heed8.gif), whether the Home/Overview request status is 200? For the bootstrap CSS or JQuery reference, perhaps the issue is related to the path or route, have you ever changed them? Can you share the related code in the layout page or the routing configure? Besides, about your application, I want to confirm with you whether it is an asp.net core MVC application or not? And which version are you using?

Comment: I did as you mentioned with the network panel i had my scripts and stylesheet redmaket and it was set to 404 instead of 200. I have not changed them, and yes im using MVC asp.net core 3.1. I will post my layout code at the start section :) @Zhi Lv

Comment: Hi @DanielEriksson, it seems that the issue is related to the file path, generally the bootstrap and jquery library are in the `lib` folder, you could check my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using IActionResult?
Try:

```
public ActionResult Overview()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and in view part remove the @RendorBody(), Layout = "~/Views/Home/Overview";

use this instead :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Overview";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Overview";
    
}

<h1>Overview</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
> <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
>
> <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
> <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
> <!--FontAwsome Link-->
> <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> <script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="./vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
> ```

About the static file 404 error, I think the issue is related to the file path.

I have created a new Asp.net core 3.1 applications on my side, and try to create a new layout page using your code, **generally, the client-side library (such as JQuery and Bootstrap) was installed in the `lib` folder** as below, but in your code, you want to load the js and css file from the `vender` folder,

[image]

So, if I using your code, the related JS and CSS file will show 404 error. Try to check the structure in the `wwwroot` folder, and load the Jquery and Boostrap from the `lib` folder.

In my sample, I'm using the default installed library, and install the `font-awesome` in the `lib` folder, so, my custom layout as below:

_CustomLayout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>BugTracker</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="~/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--FontAwsome Link-->
    <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    @RenderBody()

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading"><h2>Hello<i class="fas fa-bug"></h2></i></div>
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Overview", "Home")" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Projects</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Tickets</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></button>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Projects</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tickets</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Overview</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1 class="mt-4">Welcome User <i class="fas fa-bug"></i></h1>
                <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
                <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Code in the Home controller:

```
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult OverView()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Code in the About.cshtml page (using the default layout page):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>About</h1>

<a href="@Url.Action("Overview", "Home")" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
```

Code in the OverView.cshtml page:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "OverView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CustomLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>OverView</h1>
```

The result like this:

[image]